# XSLT copy element from one xml to other xml if some element matches

Tags: xslt, saxon

I have following xml's:

notifications-source-path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Notifications>
    <Notification>
        <NotifId>1</NotifId>
        <MsgText>
            <![CDATA[notif 1]]>
        </MsgText>
    </Notification>
    <Notification>
        <NotifId>2</NotifId>
        <MsgText>
            <![CDATA[notif 2]]>
        </MsgText>
    </Notification>
</Notifications>
```

and notifications.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Notifications>
    <BatchId>1123213333</BatchId>
    <Notification>
        <NotifId>1</NotifId>
        <EmailNotification>
            <SenderAddress>abc@def.ghi</SenderAddress>
            <Subject>SBJ2</Subject>
        </EmailNotification>
    </Notification>
    <Notification>
        <NotifId>2</NotifId>
        <EmailNotification>
            <SenderAddress>jkl.mno@pqr</SenderAddress>
            <Subject>SBJ2</Subject>
        </EmailNotification>
    </Notification>
</Notifications>
```

I need to copy `<MsgText>` from notifications-source-path.xml to notifications.xml (Notifications/Notification/EmailNotification/MsgText after tag Subject) if `<NotifId>` matches. Could someone please show me the way how to properly implement this? I'm planning to use saxon-he library for this.

edit:

so till now I've created this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"
                cdata-section-elements="MsgText"/>

    <xsl:param name="notifications-source-path" select="'html_notifications.xml'"/>

    <xsl:template match="Notifications/Notification">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="NotifId"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NotifId">
        <xsl:variable name="current.notifId" select="NotifId/text()"/>

        <MsgText>
            <xsl:copy-of
                    select="document($notifications-source-path)/Notifications/Notification/NotifId/../MsgText/node()"/>
        </MsgText>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and it selects me the MsgText from html_notifications. But I don't know how to compare the NotifId and then apply that selected MsgText to target xml.

edit2:
output should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Notifications>
  <BatchId>1123213333</BatchId>
  <Notification>
    <NotifId>1</NotifId>
    <EmailNotification>
      <SenderAddress>abc@def.ghi</SenderAddress>
      <Subject>SBJ2</Subject>
      <MsgText><![CDATA[notif 1]]></MsgText>
      <TransferTime>2017-12-31T10:00:99</TransferTime>
    </EmailNotification>
  </Notification>
  <Notification>
    <NotifId>2</NotifId>
    <EmailNotification>
      <SenderAddress>jkl.mno@pqr</SenderAddress>
      <Subject>SBJ2</Subject>
      <MsgText><![CDATA[notif 2]]></MsgText>
      <TransferTime>2017-12-31T10:00:99</TransferTime>
    </EmailNotification>
  </Notification>
</Notifications>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help] and read [ask].  StackOverflow works best if you post what you have done so far. Questions that look like "please write my code for me" (even if you didn't intend it that way) generally get downvoted and put on hold as off-topic.  If you show what you've tried and explain what isn't working (include stack trace and/or error messages where appropriate) you are ***much*** more likely to get help.  Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't know how to compare the NotifId and then apply that
>   selected MsgText to target xml.

You're using Saxon-HE, and the latest version of Saxon-HE supports XSLT 3.0, and XSLT 3.0 has a new instruction xsl:merge that is custom-made for this requirement. You want something like this (*revised to take into account new information about the required result*):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="3.0" expand-text="yes">

    <!--<xsl:variable name="notifications" select="doc('notifications.xml')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="notifications-source-path" select="doc('notifications-source-path.xml')"/>-->

    <xsl:variable name="notifications">
        <Notifications>
            <BatchId>1123213333</BatchId>
            <Notification>
                <NotifId>1</NotifId>
                <EmailNotification>
                    <SenderAddress>abc@def.ghi</SenderAddress>
                    <Subject>SBJ2</Subject>
                </EmailNotification>
            </Notification>
            <Notification>
                <NotifId>2</NotifId>
                <EmailNotification>
                    <SenderAddress>jkl.mno@pqr</SenderAddress>
                    <Subject>SBJ2</Subject>
                </EmailNotification>
            </Notification>
        </Notifications>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="notifications-source-path">
        <Notifications>
            <Notification>
                <NotifId>1</NotifId>
                <MsgText>
                    <![CDATA[notif 1]]>
                </MsgText>
            </Notification>
            <Notification>
                <NotifId>2</NotifId>
                <MsgText>
                    <![CDATA[notif 2]]>
                </MsgText>
            </Notification>
        </Notifications>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
        <Notifications>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$notifications//BatchId"/>
            <xsl:merge>
                <xsl:merge-source name="notifications" select="$notifications/*/Notification">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="NotifId"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-source name="notifications-source-path"
                    select="$notifications-source-path/*/Notification">
                    <xsl:merge-key select="NotifId"/>
                </xsl:merge-source>
                <xsl:merge-action>
                    <Notification>
                        <NotifId>{(current-merge-group()/NotifId)[1]}</NotifId>
                        <EmailNotification>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-merge-group()/EmailNotification/*, current-merge-group()/MsgText"/>
                        </EmailNotification>
                    </Notification>
                </xsl:merge-action>
            </xsl:merge>
        </Notifications>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This delivers the expected result except (a) the TransferTime element is missing - I can't see where you get that from, and (b) XSLT can't copy CDATA sections from the input to the output - the CDATA here performs no useful purpose anyway.

If you want an XSLT 2.0 solution you could achieve a very similar result using xsl:for-each-group. Here's this version:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" exclude-result-prefixes="xs math"
    version="2.0">

    <!--<xsl:variable name="notifications" select="doc('notifications.xml')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="notifications-source-path" select="doc('notifications-source-path.xml')"/>-->

    <xsl:variable name="notifications">
        <Notifications>
            <BatchId>1123213333</BatchId>
            <Notification>
                <NotifId>1</NotifId>
                <EmailNotification>
                    <SenderAddress>abc@def.ghi</SenderAddress>
                    <Subject>SBJ2</Subject>
                </EmailNotification>
            </Notification>
            <Notification>
                <NotifId>2</NotifId>
                <EmailNotification>
                    <SenderAddress>jkl.mno@pqr</SenderAddress>
                    <Subject>SBJ2</Subject>
                </EmailNotification>
            </Notification>
        </Notifications>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="notifications-source-path">
        <Notifications>
            <Notification>
                <NotifId>1</NotifId>
                <MsgText>
                    <![CDATA[notif 1]]>
                </MsgText>
            </Notification>
            <Notification>
                <NotifId>2</NotifId>
                <MsgText>
                    <![CDATA[notif 2]]>
                </MsgText>
            </Notification>
        </Notifications>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="main">
        <Notifications>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$notifications//BatchId"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="($notifications, $notifications-source-path)/*/Notification" group-by="NotifId">
                    <Notification>
                        <NotifId><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></NotifId>
                        <EmailNotification>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/EmailNotification/*, current-group()/MsgText"/>
                        </EmailNotification>
                    </Notification>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </Notifications>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hello, unfortunately this only copies values of elements not element tags. And I'm using saxon Saxon-HE-9.6.0-6.jar som I'm not usre if there is also XLST 3.0. I'm beginner with xslt.

Comment: You haven't shown your desired output so I had to guess. Switch to Saxon-HE 9.8 if you want XSLT 3.0 support.

Comment: I've updated the question with target. I'd like to switch and will do if there is no other option, but I'm using some product which already contains this library. If there is no other option with version which is there, I will create new jar which will be executed somehow, but I'd like to stick with currently used version for simplicity.

Comment: OK, I think the main difference from my guess is that you want the MsgText inside the EmailNotification, not outside it. I'll edit the example to achieve that. Note that you can't preserve CDATA sections through an XSLT transformation, as you appear to want.

Comment: wont CDATA be preserved with `<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="MsgText"/>`?

Comment: That will put CDATA in the output whether or not it was present in the input, so it can't be said to be "preserved".

Comment: I don't know if I'm doing something wrong but this is not giving my the result. Basically notifications.xml is xml which I need to process notifications and only replace/add MsgText with MsgText from notification-source.xml if in notification-source.xml NotifId equals NotifId of current Notification. If there is no matching NotifiId then leave current notification unchanged.

Comment: Well, it would help to describe the requirements up front rather than adding them incrementally when the original question is answered. Sorry, I've spent enough time on this now.