# XSLT copy elements from xml by element match

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation, saxon

I need to replace some element in processing xml with element from other xml if some parameters matches. Basically notifications.xml is xml in which I need to process notifications and only replace/add MsgText with MsgText from notification-source.xml if in notification-source.xml NotifId equals NotifId of current Notification. If there is no match then preserve the notification unchanged.

notifications.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Notifications>
  <BatchId>DOCATTR.BATCHID</BatchId>
  <Notification>
    <NotifId>1</NotifId>
    <Cid>DOCATTR.CID</Cid>
    <EmailNotification>
      <CcAddress>DOCATTR.EMAILCC</CcAddress>
      <CcName>DOCATTR.EMAILCCNAME</CcName>
      <BccAddress>DOCATTR.EMAILBCC</BccAddress>
      <SenderAddress>DOCATTR.SENDERADDRESS</SenderAddress>
      <SenderName>DOCATTR.SENDERNAME</SenderName>
      <MsgText>
      </MsgText>
      <Expiration>DOCATTR.EXPIRATION</Expiration>
      <Priority>DOCATTR.PRIORITYNC</Priority>
    </EmailNotification>
  </Notification>
</Notifications>
```

notifications-source.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Notifications>
    <Notification>
        <NotifId>1</NotifId>
        <MsgText>
            <![CDATA[notif 1]]>
        </MsgText>
    </Notification>
    <Notification>
        <NotifId>2</NotifId>
        <MsgText>
            <![CDATA[notif 2]]>
        </MsgText>
    </Notification>
</Notifications>
```

This is what I was trying, but it's copying msgText somewhere else

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"                    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" cdata-section-elements="MsgText"/>
  <xsl:variable name="notifications" select="/"/>
  <xsl:variable name="notifications-source" select="document('notifications-source.xml')"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Notifications>
      <xsl:for-each select="$notifications//Notification">
        <xsl:variable name="currentNotifId" select="./NotifId"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$notifications-source//Notification">
          <xsl:variable name="remoteNotifId" select="./NotifId"/>
          <xsl:if test="$currentNotifId=$remoteNotifId">
            <xsl:copy>
              <xsl:copy-of select="./MsgText"/>
            </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </Notifications>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

it would be fine to use saxon-he 9.6.0-6 for this, but If not applicable it can be newer one.

So I've changed template to this one:

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MsgText">
        <xsl:variable name="currentNotifId" select="../NotifId/text()"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$notifications-source/Notifications/Notification/NotifId[text() = $currentNotifId]">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="$notifications-source/Notifications/Notification/NotifId[text() = $currentNotifId]/../MsgText"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="'test'"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

Now I'm only matching the MsgText. But currently I always get `<MsgText><![CDATA[test]]></MsgText>` so I gues I'm not properly using test (choose)

Comment: Is that question different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44762709/xslt-copy-element-from-one-xml-to-other-xml-if-some-element-matches or why do you ask a new one? And you are supposed to show us the result you want for the input samples you posted if you want us to understand what you want to achieve, given that your code does so far not achieve it.

Comment: As I can't delete the old question I'm asking new one with (I hope) better description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path `<xsl:variable name="currentNotifId" select="../NotifId/text()"/>` is not right, should be `<xsl:variable name="currentNotifId" select="../../NotifId/text()"/>`.

You might want to learn to use a key instead and simply put the condition into a match pattern:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="notifications-source">
<Notifications>
    <Notification>
        <NotifId>1</NotifId>
        <MsgText>
            <![CDATA[notif 1]]>
        </MsgText>
    </Notification>
    <Notification>
        <NotifId>2</NotifId>
        <MsgText>
            <![CDATA[notif 2]]>
        </MsgText>
    </Notification>
</Notifications>        
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:key name="note-ref" match="Notification/MsgText" use="../NotifId"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="MsgText[key('note-ref', ../../NotifId, $notifications-source)]">  
       <xsl:copy-of select="key('note-ref', ../../NotifId, $notifications-source)"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/93dEHFX.

Comment: Thank you, I used it my way (with fixed path)...when I execute your template within Intellij IDE I'm getting following error: `[ERROR]: Could not compile stylesheet
[FATAL]: Error checking type of the expression 'funcall(key, [literal-expr(note-ref), ParentLocationPath(ParentLocationPath(step("parent", -1), step("parent", -1)), step("child", 16)), parameter-ref(notifications-source/reference)])'.`

Comment: That error message very much suggests you are trying to use  that XSLT 2.0 code with an XSLT 1.0 processor although you told us you use Saxon 9.

Comment: I'm using saxon 2 in java...but I was testing some basic features in IDE. Thanks for pointing that out.